# Value passed to a javascript function changes when arrive

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I pass a facebook album ID to a function and when it arrives that value changes:

ALBUMID is like **somenumbers333** And the function shows somenumbers332

I notice that it happens when referrer fanpage albums are similar to the fanpage id at its three last digits(333) and the FanPage is ended at the same three digits-1 (332).
Albums from some FanPages have that pattern: three last digits similar. There are some ones that their albums finish (at this example) all of them at 333 or at 332 and the FanPage Id is finished at 332 (I dont't know the reason). If I send the value to the function somenumbers332 so the album id finishes with same three digits, it shows the correct album id. It's only when this pattern happens: If album ids are totally different to the FanPage ID it would show the value correctly.

But in the other situations, how is it possible the value changes during its flight to the function?

Try it with your access token if the one here doesn't work. I'll try to keep it updated.
First code has the problem (pattern).
Second not

```js
var html="";
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/120185216968/albums?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAN8ifZBF4oeOgbBcq6TDqpz4SeFWAT6jg84uZB23lMQQnFtH3AvZBZBea5i0TVpXZCHCJlLjk0HZB0GhJalqq29MS3qhBgUme95Q02ZBXMoJkwuIH0SkgLYFTWUdyNuZCsKvAzFqAJAstUliawp1ZCXQc4WnqnIkGUjZCzLBMAaUm1N4NbWTJcQ7IbcR2P5mzPUQd6ZAKLrJQI9";

$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
  $.each(json.data, function(i, fb) {
    html += "<br><div onclick='func(" + fb.id + ")' style='background:red'>ClickToSee " + fb.id + "</div>";
  });
  $('#iddiv').html(html);
});

function func(id) {
  $('#showID').append('<br>' + id);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showID" style="background:#0C6">Show id here</div>
<div id="iddiv"></div>
```

```js
var html="";
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/217557721786669/albums?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAN8ifZBF4oeOgbBcq6TDqpz4SeFWAT6jg84uZB23lMQQnFtH3AvZBZBea5i0TVpXZCHCJlLjk0HZB0GhJalqq29MS3qhBgUme95Q02ZBXMoJkwuIH0SkgLYFTWUdyNuZCsKvAzFqAJAstUliawp1ZCXQc4WnqnIkGUjZCzLBMAaUm1N4NbWTJcQ7IbcR2P5mzPUQd6ZAKLrJQI9";

$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
  $.each(json.data, function(i, fb) {
    html += "<br><div onclick='func(" + fb.id + ")' style='background:red'>ClickToSee " + fb.id + "</div>";
  });
  $('#iddiv').html(html);
});

function func(id) {
  $('#showID').append('<br>' + id);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showID" style="background:#0C6">Show id here</div>
<div id="iddiv"></div>
```

Comment: Tried different inputs/data? Or is it applicable to just this case?

Comment: It's only at these cases. I've edited and put the full code working. As you can see is a simple code with no reason to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Added the code for both situations so you can see mystery results

Comment: You're going to want to initialise `html` as an empty string, unless you want `"undefined<br><div onclick..."`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. The undefined showed at first element is not the problem.

Comment: @LuisGar Gar - You do know that Facebook expires its tokens periodically, so nobody will be able to run the script you posted.

Comment: I'll try to keep it updated. I've just updated it now. Please. Try now and say to me I am not crazy.

Comment: Nope. You're not crazy! I see it too.

Comment: Thanks! But the answer is that is makeing that to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is caused by some integer overflow. Best bet is to transport the ID as a string to avoid all the complications.

Here I've slightly modified your function to pass values as strings and it seems to be working fine.

```js
var html="";
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/120185216968/albums?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAN8ifZBF4oeOgbBcq6TDqpz4SeFWAT6jg84uZB23lMQQnFtH3AvZBZBea5i0TVpXZCHCJlLjk0HZB0GhJalqq29MS3qhBgUme95Q02ZBXMoJkwuIH0SkgLYFTWUdyNuZCsKvAzFqAJAstUliawp1ZCXQc4WnqnIkGUjZCzLBMAaUm1N4NbWTJcQ7IbcR2P5mzPUQd6ZAKLrJQI9";

$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
  $.each(json.data, function(i, fb) {
    html += "<br><div onclick='func(\"" + fb.id + "\")' style='background:red'>ClickToSee " + fb.id + "</div>";
  });
  $('#iddiv').html(html);
});

function func(id) {
  $('#showID').append('<br>' + id);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showID" style="background:#0C6">Show id here</div>
<div id="iddiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I thought i,d tried that but probably with mistakes. Many thanks!!

Comment: The mystery continues but I just can make my work. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I've been testing this snippet. Oddly it happens only for ODD numbers - i.e in binary if the last bit is 1, it gets converted into a 0. 69 becomes 68, 71 becomes 70, but 72 remains 72, 70 remains 70

Comment: Edited the code. Now it sums +1 a seven changed to the first position. But if the number has less digits do not happen the change

Comment: Yeah. I see that. Usually if the problem happens when the digits go higher, then that points to a buffer overflow error. Or the number which needs to be represented is higher than javascript's max supported number. 

But `1.79E+308` is the MAX_INT value of javascript. The facebook id is definitely less that this. Thats what confuses me.

Comment: I didn't saw this happened only with ODD numbers. Then nothing related to facebook and the id of fanpage (it was a coincidence.  I don't know what I was thinking).  It happens only with 17 digits. 22222222222222273 Shows: 22222222222222270 ; 12222222222222273 Shows: 12222222222222272;  42222222222222273 or This: 32222222222222273 Shows: 42222222222222270

Comment: Maybe you just discovered a javascript bug. In this simplest form, this shows error:

`function func(id){

  alert(id);

}

func(12222222222222273);` as `12222222222222272`

Comment: OK Champion! It happens with 17 digits or more. Could be the lenght of the string number too? 17 digits 8 * 2 +1 ?

Comment: I'm not sure if must be proud! What simple is... And I was thinking it was related to facebook

Comment: There's a similar issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428772/javascript-number-string-div-onclick-strange-conversion