# Javascript Number-String DIV onclick strange conversion

Tags: javascript, facebook

What I basically do is that I assign the Facebook-ID from a person to a onclick-Event in a DIV. The div is a string itself because I assign it later to a DOM-property via innerHTML

```
"<div onclick='openFbFriend(" + friendsArray[i]['facebookID'] + ");' class='row'>";
```

Now the openFbFriend does simply open the Facebook-Page of this person:

```
function openFbFriend(fbID) {
    window.open("https://www.facebook.com/" + fbID, "_blank");
}
```

Does work for most people. What I experienced now is that some Links are broken I'll redirected e.g. to this page: https://www.facebook.com/10204840506352732

I investigated and very strange but it happens that when the FB-ID is longer than or equal to 17 digits than my string is changed from the div to openFbFriend with plus or minors 1. How could that happen? The fb-id is never converted to a number and is always a string. So if I console.log the fbid after div the id is correct. But sth. weird happens then when clicked because if fbid>=17digits than in openFbFriend it is +-1.
Any help appreciated :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try

```
"<div onclick='openFbFriend(\"" + friendsArray[i]['facebookID'] + "\");' class='row'>";
```

because if you do not have the `\"` around the argument, then it will be interpreted as an integer or if it contains non-numeric characters then it will result in an error.

The resulting string would be:

```
<div onclick='openFbFriend("10204840506352732");' class='row'>
```

But in your version:

```
<div onclick='openFbFriend(10204840506352732);' class='row'>
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation :)
But I still do not understand why it is interpreted as an integer because it is saved as string in Array

Comment: Look at what will be the JavaScript that gets executed: It is either `openFbFriend("10204840506352732");` (here the number is in quotation marks and thus the JavaScript-Interpreter interprets it as a string) or `openFbFriend(10204840506352732);` (here the number is not in quotation marks and will thus be interpreted as integer). maybe executing those two: `alert(  "1"  +1);` and `alert(  1  +1);` might give you the understanding if you compare the results.

Comment: yes but friendsArray[i]['facebookID'] is already "10204840506352732" and not 10204840506352732. So I think I didn't get it yet. Because as I understand your example and my described behavior a[0] = "1"; alert(1 + a[0]) will print 2 and alert(1 + "" +a[0]) will print 11. Nevertheless now it is working. Thank you! I'll try out my example and see...

Comment: There is an important difference between your examples in the latest comment and that one in the original question. If you click on an element `<div onclick='openFbFriend(10204840506352732);' class='row'>`, then the browser will internally `eval` your JavaScript, so it executes `eval("openFbFriend(10204840506352732);")` (with no variables in it, only a _constant_ integer). There is a difference between (a) `var x = "1"; eval("alert(" + x + " + 1");` (equal to `eval("alert(1 + 1)");`) and just (b) `var x = "1"; alert(x + 1)` with no `eval`. In (b) you are completely right. But you have (a) here

Answer (score 0):

Now I had a quick own guess and fixed it with

```
    \"


    "<div onclick='openFbFriend(\"" + friendsArray[i]['facebookID'] + "\");' class='row'>"
```

I assume it is converted to a number without \" but I do not understand why. Maybe sb can explain? Thx